# Problems using Google Maps on mobile-chrome-apps(CCA) v0.5.1

Tags: android, google-maps, google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-app

I'm currently trying to create a project with "mobile-chrome-apps(CCA) v0.5.1" using the Google Maps, however when I try to use the plugin.google.maps appears some errors in java compilation. And if I try to use without the GoogleMaps plugin, only including the scripts of API, does not occur errors but the map its not displayed.

This is strange, because if I compile without the CCA, only with the cordova, the GoogleMaps functions work normally.

**my manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "UTFPR",
    "description": "A Sample Chrome App",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                "background.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "geolocation",
        "fileSystem",
        "videoCapture",
        "background",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="101" android:versionName="0.1.1" package="com.marcelodolce.UTFPR" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
</manifest>
```

> **Errors**
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRN6H.png
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBpz2.png

Does anyone know a solution?

If I run without this plugin, with only "new google.maps.map", I need some specific permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the errors you're getting?

Comment: yes of course! added!

Comment: I don't see the errors yet..  May you file an issue at https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues please?